# ¿Es posible saber si un archivo lo esta ocupando otra aplicación, objeto file?

Tags: java

Tengo este código, en el cual entra a validar si el archivo existe, pero me arroja una excepción si otra aplicación esta escribiendo el archivo, lo cual es así.
Pero necesito, cachar cuando lo estén ocupando, para mandar un mensaje.

Error :

> Error interno java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The process cannot
>   access the file because it is being used by another process)

Código:

```
               for (File file : filesList) {

                    responseCreaXML = new ResponseDetalleXMLDto();

                    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {

                        String name_tmp = file.getName();

                        if(name_tmp.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
                        {
                          System.out.println("ARCHIVO "+file.getName());
                        }
                    }
               }
```

Comment: Revisa si de alguna forma te pueda servir esta referencia lo he mirado por encima y creo que lo puedas utilizar: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir un try catch a la excepción y mostrar un mensaje por pantalla al usuario cuando ese error ocurra de la siguiente forma:

```
     for (File file : filesList) {

                responseCreaXML = new ResponseDetalleXMLDto();

                if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {

                    try{

                        String name_tmp = file.getName();

                        if(name_tmp.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
                        {
                          System.out.println("ARCHIVO "+file.getName());
                        }

                    }catch(IOException e){
                        System.out.println(e.getCause());
                    }

                }
           }
```

Comment: La idea es buena, pero el código del manejo de errores invita a una mala práctica.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo de esa forma, sin embargo. Como comentan, puede llegar a ser una mala practica. 
Por otro lado, no he encontrado algo, un método u objeto que me indique con exactitud esta acción.
Gracias.